# all Files Checkined each times in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I used TFS in visual studio 2013.
I dont know what happening , when I changed one files just one file and cliked on CheckIn , this message show :

> Changeset 570 successfully checked in.

[image]

each time show this . whats problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem. Each time you check in one or more files those files together gets a number, "Changeset 570", is just the number for the checkin, next will be 571, 572. 573 etc.

So the message you get is just a information stating that the checkin was completed.